# Polynomial relation with matrix coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Lemma:** Let $P$ and $Q$ be two polynomials with *matrix* coefficients, say
$$ P(x) = \sum P_{m}x^{m} \hspace{5mm} Q(x) = \sum Q_{j}x^{j}.$$ Then the product $R(x) = P(x)Q(x)$ is then $R(x) = \sum P_{m}Q_{j}x^{m+j}$. Now, suppose that $AQ_{j} = Q_{j}A$ for all $j$. Then, $R(A) = P(A)Q(A)$.

The author claims the proof is self-evident, but I'm not the brightest mathematician. Is my proof on track?

Proof:

Note that $R(x) = P(x)Q(x) = \sum P_{m}x^{m}Q_{j}x^{j} = \sum P_{m}Q_{j}x^{m+j}$

So,

$
R(A) = \sum P_{m}A^{m} \sum Q_{j}A^{j} = \sum P_{m}A^{m}Q_{j}A^{j} = \sum P_{m}Q_{j}A^{m}A^{j} = \sum P_{m}Q_{j}A^{m+j} = P(A)Q(A)$

Comment: Looks ok, but it would help to index your sums. You might also justify why $A^m Q_j = Q_j A^m$.

Comment: Added that. Thanks for your answer.